# Add a List<JToogleButton> to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a `List<JToggleButton>` and I need to add all those buttons to a panel.

The panel needs to have only a vertical scrollbar. It has a fixed size of `600 x 600` px.

Buttons have different sizes and I need them look pretty compact (for example, some rows can have two big buttons, some four smaller). I need to add the buttons **by order** from list (first with index 0, then 1 and so on..).

How to achieve this layout?

Comment: why is the panel fixed size? Actually, you can't tell - the exact layout is at the discretion of ... well .. the LayoutManager :-)

Comment: See also [procrustean](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+procrustean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try placing the `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` in a `JScrollPane` and add all the buttons.